# How to select following element in selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a div which contains a input with an identifier as id and a label in it. with my selenium method i can easily select the input as a webElement but how can i get the label webElement via the Input WebElement?

```
   <div class="item-selectable small-2 radio-item columns xsmall-12 item-selectable-stacked">
    <input id="0-3" name="RatingQuestions[0].Score" type="radio" value="3" checked="">
 <label for="0-3">
</label>
 </div>
```

This is the method in selenium to select the webElement, whcih currently selects only the input and not like it should the label.

```
public void RateQuestion(int questionnumber, int rating)
        {
            string questionid = questionnumber.ToString() + "-" + rating.ToString();
            IWebElement RateQuestionElement = this.Driver.FindElement(By.Id(questionid));
            RateQuestionElement.Click();
        }
```

The issue is that only the label is clickable and therefore i need to select the label from the input field, how can i do this?

Comment: Can you share your current code please? You should ask your question as [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've added my selenium selector code

Comment: @Simon.B Why do you need _to select the label from the input field_? What is your _usecase_? Access the `<input>` or the  `<label>`?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you don't invoke `click()` on `<label>` nodes but on `<input>` nodes.

As per the *HTML* to invoke `click()` on the `<input>` tag with respect to the `<label>` tag you can use the following solution:

```
public void RateQuestion(int questionnumber, int rating)
    {
        string questionid = questionnumber.ToString() + "-" + rating.ToString();
        IWebElement RateQuestionElement = this.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[@for='" + questionid + "']"));
        RateQuestionElement.Click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some options:

1. After you select the element with questionId, the you can continue further to select the label.
   e.g:

```js
IWebElement RateQuestionElement = this.Driver.FindElement(By.Id(questionid)); 

IWebElement RateQuestionLabel = RateQuestionElement.FindElement(By.Css("label"));



RateQuestionLabel.click();
```

or

2. You can use CssSelector 
   e.g:

```js
myCssSelector = "#myQuestionId label"

IWebElement RateQuestionElement = this.Driver.FindElement(By.Css(myCssSelector));

RateQuestionElement.click();
```

I have not tried to execute it myself, but the concept is there

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void RateQuestion(int questionnumber, int rating)
        {
            string questionid = questionnumber.ToString() + "-" + rating.ToString();
            IWebElement RateQuestionElement = this.Driver.FindElement(By.Id(questionid)).FindElement(By.Xpath("./../../label"));
            RateQuestionElement.Click();
        }
```

Or this:

```
public void RateQuestion(int questionnumber, int rating)
            {
                string questionid = questionnumber.ToString() + "-" + rating.ToString();
                IWebElement RateQuestionElement = this.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[contains(local-name(), 'label') and contains(@for, questionid)]"));
                RateQuestionElement.Click();
            }
```

The latter one - I'm not that good with C#, so perhaps you'll have to put `{questionid}` there, rather than just `questionid`.